# TDD: Adding a method to test state

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

So, I'm starting to write some logic for a simple program (toy game on the side).  You have a specific ship (called a setup) that is a ship + modules.  You start with an empty setup based off a ship and then add modules to that setup.  Ships also have a numbered array of module positions.

```
var setup = new Setup(ship); // ship is a stub (IShip) defined someplace else
var module = new Mock<IModule>().Object;
setup.AddModule(module, 1); // 1 = which position
```

So, this is the code in my test method.  I now need to assert on this code.  Well, I need a getter method right?

```
Assert.AreEqual(module, setup.GetModule(1));
```

This might sound really dumb and I'm worrying about nothing, but for some stupid reason I'm concerned with adding a method just to assert that a test passed.

Is this fine and is in fact part of the design process that TDD is pushing out?  For instance I *know* I need an AddModule method because I want to test it, and the fact that this requires a GetModule method to test is simply an evolution of my design via TDD.

Or is this kind of a smell because I don't even know if I'll really need GetModule in my code and it will only be used in a test?

For example, adding a module is going to ultimately affect different stats of a setup (armor, shield, firepower, etc).  The thing is those are going to be complex, and I wanted to start with a simple test.  But in the end, those are the public attributes I care about -- a setup is defined by its stats, not by a list of modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.  I'm glad to hear you're writing the tests first.

If you let the design manifest itself through the tests, you're more likely to build only the parts you'll need.  But is this the best design?  Maybe not, but don't let that discourage you -- your add method works!

It may be too early to tell if you'll need the GetModule method later.  For now, build up the functionality you need and go green, then slowly refactor it (going from red to green again) to get the design you want.

Answer (score 2):

Part of evolving the design is to start with baby steps like a simple method and then grow into the complex stats (eventually dropping this method and changing the test) when enough supports it. When doing TDD, don't expect that the first test you write is targeting the ideal interface. It is OK to have some messiness that will get dropped as you evolve the design.

That being said, if you see no public purpose to the method, try to limit its visibility as much as is reasonable to the test code. Although even that should eventually go away as you get to build out the rest of the system and have something real to test as a side effect of the set method.

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary of introducing a public method in my class that is only used for testing.

There are various ways how you could test this:

**Reflection**: The GetModule method is a private method in your class (this could also work if your 'stats' are private) and you can access it in your test method via reflection. This will work well, the only trouble is you will not get any compiler errors if you change the name of the private method or add / delete some variables (but, of course, your test will fail and you will know early)

**Inheritance**: The GetModule method could be protected (only inheritance visible) and your test class could inherit from the main class. This way your test class gets access to this method, but this is not really exposed to the outside world.

**Assert the side-effect**: This is where you really think about what it means to add a module to the system. If it is going to affect some 'stats' as you put it, you could write tests which assert that the stats are appropriately modified.

Comment: Or you could add the InternalsVisibleTo attribute to let your tests see internal methods.